# ADF Script Creating a Table with Parquet format using INFER_SCHEMA in Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from Salesforce to Snowflake using ADF avoiding use SAS Token, because of that I going to use integration storage on Snowflake.

I'm trying to follow this example: https://medium.com/snowflake/seamless-migration-to-snowflake-using-adf-script-activity-schema-detection-25475ea86a09.

I already create the integration storage, format type (parquet) and a Stage.

The problem is in the script activity: when I try to create a table using `INFER_SCHEMA`, I always get the same error:

> Operation on target Script1 failed: ERROR [22000] Cannot perform operation. This session does not have a current schema. Call 'USE SCHEMA', or use a qualified name.

When I run the same query in Snowflake it works!

```
--This is the query that I'm trying to run from script activity

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "DEV_LANDING_CRM_DB"."POC_CCV".Account
 using template (select array_agg(object_construct(*))
     from table(infer_schema(location=>'@adf_copyparquetfile_stage_dev/Account', file_format=>'DEV_PARQUET_TYPE'
         )
     )
 );
```

I realize when I run the query without "infer_schema" it works.

Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMKLj.png)

I already try to put another scripts Use Role; Use Warehouse; Use Database; Use Schema; each in a different script (in the same script activity).

I put the same query into a stored procedure and call but I got the same error:

> Error creating or replacing table: Cannot perform operation. This session does not have a current schema. Call 'USE SCHEMA', or use a qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution...the problem was I was referencing to the stage of the integration storage in wrong manner:

```html
...
table(infer_schema(location=>'@adf_copyparquetfile_stage_dev/Account', file_format=>'DEV_PARQUET_TYPE')));
```

But I realize that the route for the stage was different in snowflake and I chaged it (The best way to find the route o name go to snowflake in worksheets go to databases and find the stage press 3 dots and "place name in Editor"):

```html
...
table(infer_schema(location=>'@DEV_LANDING_CRM_DB.POC_CCV.ADF_COPYPARQUETFILE_STAGE_DEV', file_format=>'DEV_PARQUET_TYPE')));
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Error creating or replacing table: Cannot perform operation. This session does not have a current schema. Call 'USE SCHEMA', or use a qualified name."

The cause of error is the issue with the stagging you created with Blob storage.

When you are **configuring a Snowflake storage integration** you have to Grant Snowflake Access to the Storage Locations by adding `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to service principal created by Snowflake in your tenant.

- The role possessing the OWNERSHIP privilege on the stage must also have the USAGE privilege on the storage integration.
- Also check the user have appropriate USAGE privilege on the storage integration.

Follow this document to create [Snowflake storage integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config)